# Can't order test case in Requirement based Test Suite - Test manager 2010

Tags: testcase, microsoft-test-manager

In Test Manager 2010 It seems that I can't order test cases in a Requirement based Test Suite (ordering a test cases in normal test suite works fine)
Please anyone explain me why they forbid me to do that, or suggest a way to work around
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How to order / reorganize order of testcases?

Ordnen von Testcases / Testfällen

Ändern der Reihenfolge von Testcases / Testfällen

**Workaround**

- create 2 suites, one of them query based
- customize the query of the query based suite and run it
- select all needed testcases and copy them to the clipboard
- insert them in the manual suite order them by
- use "order" from the menue-bar by changing the values in criteria order
- delete the query based suite
- have fun

http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dd997699.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Just ran into this myself.  It turns out that requirement-based test suites are a special case of a query-based suite, which also cannot be ordered.  All test cases linked to a requirement / user story will show in the corresponding test suite.

As for work-arounds to the default sort order (apparently, the test case's work item ID), I couldn't find any.  However, you could approximate the requirement-based query with a regular query, and then use the query-based suite's sort order capability.  There are two problems with this: (1) the requirements that a test case is associated with are not available in the query editor, so you'd have to use some other criteria; and (2) you still don't have ad-hoc test case ordering control like you would with a non-query test suite.

I didn't find anything about adding any ordering capability to requirement-based test suites in an upcoming version, or in any third-party tool.  Might be something to look into creating.

---

refs:

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vstsqualitytools/archive/2009/06/04/no-more-missed-requirements.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286578.aspx